# How can I use var in resource calling

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm importing roles which already have been created in AWS console and unfortunately the names are strange. So in order to use those roles I am trying like this
I've two IAM roles as follows

```
data "aws_iam_role" "reithera-rtcov201" {
  name = "exomcloudrosareitherartcov-YRX1M2GJKD6H"
}

data "aws_iam_role" "dompe-rlx0120" {
  name = "exomcloudrosadomperlx0120p-1SCGY0RG5JXFF"
}
```

In this file I have 2 variables as follows:

```
sponsor = ["reithera", "dompe"]
study   = ["rtcov201", "rlx0120"]
```

I'm trying in the following way, but terraform doesn't allow to use $.

```
data.aws_iam_role.${var.sponsor}-${var.study}.arn
```

Do you know any solution for this.

Comment: Most languages do not allow variable name interpolation (Ruby being an example of an exception). It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here though, since both `sponsor` and `study` variables are type `list(string)` and therefore could not be interpolated regardless. Please update the question with at least pseudo-code or explaining the variables' intent.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. You can dynamically create references to resources.
Instead of two separate data sources you should create one:

```
variable "iam_roles"
 default = ["exomcloudrosareitherartcov-YRX1M2GJKD6H", "exomcloudrosadomperlx0120p-1SCGY0RG5JXFF"]
}
```

and then

```
data "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  for_each = toset(var.iam_roles)
  name = each.key
}
```

and you can refer to them using role name:

```
data.aws_iam_role["exomcloudrosareitherartcov-YRX1M2GJKD6H"].arn
```